# NuGet Restore Resolving Packages from private NuGet Azure artifacts with Incorrect Folder Structure on macOS

Tags: .net, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I am encountering an issue while restoring packages from private NuGet Azure artifacts. When the packages are restored, they end up being resolved with their name as part of the folder structure.

For example, if I restore a package named Package.Name, the NuGet is placed in the .nuget folder as \.nuget\Packages\package.name\1.0.0\lib\netstandard2.0\package.name.dll. However, it should be restored as \.nuget\Packages\package.name\1.0.0\"lib\netstandard2.0\package.name.dll". So the file is being named : lib\netstandard2.0\package.name.dll, instead of creating the folder structure. This is causing a MSB3106 error during build, since the MSBuild process is looking for the package in the correct directory but NuGet restore does not place it there.

I am using a MacBook Pro M2 running macOS Ventura. Strangely enough, when I use packages like Newtonsoft.Json, they are restored normally with the correct folder structure. Furthermore, when I work on the same solution on my Dell (running Windows), the restore process works normally and builds correctly.

The solution I am trying to restore is a C# .NET 6 project. Can anyone help me understand why this is happening and how to resolve it?

I have attempted to resolve the issue by manually renaming the affected files and then attempting to build the project. This approach worked for the specific package, as the error message disappeared. However, since there are over 50 packages being restored from the private Azure artifacts, this is not a scalable solution. Additionally, every time I clean my NuGet folder, the problem reoccurs.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR unless you give us more information (packages I can investigate myself), my guess is that the package incorrectly uses `\` directory separators in the zip file's central directory, rather than `/`. It's a package authoring problem, that the client doesn't have a mitigation for.

More detail: On Windows, both `/` and `\` are directory separators, but on Linux and Mac, only `/` is (therefore, I believe the example you used in your question is technically wrong, I believe it should be  `/.nuget/Packages/package.name/1.0.0/lib\netstandard2.0\package.name.dll`, where `lib\netstandard2.0\package.name.dll` is a filename in the `1.0.0` directory). Since `\` is not a special file/directory character on Linux and Mac, as it is on Windows, files are allowed to contain this character.

For this reason, when NuGet creates packages, with official tooling (`dotnet pack`, `msbuild -t:pack`, `nuget.exe pack`), it always normalizes the path separators to `/` before adding the file to the zip's central directory record. However, many other zip programs (for example, PowerShell's `Create-Archive`) does not, so when you create a zip file on Windows, since `\` is the default path separator, it will write zip files with `\` in the zip's central directory.

Finally, I don't know why it was implemented this way, but NuGet's package extraction code doesn't attempt to rewrite the paths to use the operating system's directory separator character, since it assumes that pack already normalized to the separator that works on all operating systems. So, NuGet calculates the package base directory, then does `Path.Combine(basePath, relativeFilePath)`. Therefore, packages created by tools other than NuGet, and use Windows directory separators, will end up as files with `\` in the names, rather than in subdirectories.

At this time, there's no alternative than to tell the package author that their package has a bug and needs to be fixed.

Comment: I can take a look at the packages myself and will let you know if this is the case, thanks for the hints! I'll keep you posted how goes.